# A college consists of $4$ professors and $8$ students. In how many ways can a party of four to be chosen so as to include at least one professor?

Tags: combinatorics

The Solution I have tried:

$$^8C_3 \cdot ^4C_1= 224$$
But answer is wrong.

The correct answers mentioned in mcqs are: $325,~425,~525,~625$

Comment: The answer you have written includes *exactly one* professor whereas we need *at least one* professor.

Comment: You should say that the answers mentioned in the multiple choice question are $325$, $425$, $525$, $625$.  They are not all correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of ways to select 1 professor and 3 students:

$4\choose{1}$$8\choose{3}$

Number of ways to select 2 professor and 2 students:

$4\choose{2}$$8\choose{2}$

Number of ways to select 3 professor and 1 student:

$4\choose{3}$$8\choose{1}$

Number of ways to select 4 professor and 0 students:

$4\choose{4}$$8\choose{0}$

Adding :$4\choose{1}$$8\choose{3}$+$4\choose{2}$$8\choose{2}$+$4\choose{3}$$8\choose{1}$+$4\choose{4}$$8\choose{0}$, you will get the answer

Answer (score 4):

The groups of four that can be formed are
$$
\binom{12}{4}
$$
but this number also includes groups with no professors. How many of these can be formed? Exactly
$$
\binom{8}{4}
$$
So the answer is
$$
\binom{12}{4}-\binom{8}{4}=425
$$

Answer (score 1):

Ways to select at least one professor is

> $$(^4C_1\cdot ^8C_3) + (^4C_2\cdot ^8C_2) + (^4C_3\cdot^8C_1) + (^4C_4\cdot^8C_0)$$

Divide the above value  by $^{12}C_4$ if you require the probability (mentioned in the tag).

Comment: Thanks @PeterForeman for both the edit and the suggestion : )